# Use spring session JDBC with existing database (not springboot)

Tags: spring, spring-session, spring-config

I have my application running with spring web mvc framework without spring boot. Now I want to use spring session JDBC to store the session to the database used by the app. All the examples I found online are using spring boot, and if not using spring boot, the datasource config they use are `EmbeddedDatabase` like this:

```
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder() 
                            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                            .addScript("org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-h2.sql").build();
    }
```

I have my datasource configuration using HikariCP and I want the spring session to use this datasource config.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driver"));
    config.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    config.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    config.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    config.setMinimumIdle(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.pool.minimumIdle", Integer.class));
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.pool.maximumPoolSize", Integer.class));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.prop.cachePrepStmts"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.prop.prepStmtCacheSize"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.prop.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit"));
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
    return ds;
}
```

How can I use my current configuration to integrate with spring session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand [spring-session javaconfig-jdbc sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/spring-session-samples/spring-session-sample-javaconfig-jdbc) / [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-jdbc-jc), you "just" need to:

1. Annotate "your config class" (`YourConfig`) with `org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.EnableJdbcHttpSession`.
2. *Name* your `DataSource` "dataSource". (done!;)
3. Provide a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean, basing on `dataSource` in `YourConfig`.
4. (in a servlet environment - as yours) Introduce an `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` (in class path) referencing `YourConfig`:

   ```
   public class Initializer extends org.springframework.session.web.context.AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer { // <1>

     public Initializer() {
       super(YourConfig.class); // <2>
     }
   }
   ```

---

If you wish to **install** the **db schema manually** or with an **external tool**, the SQL scripts are located in spring-session.jar(!org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-@@platform@@.sql) file or respectively [in the source code repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc).

---

These (application.)properties allow further customization:

```
# Session store type. [jdbc|redis|hazelcast|mongodb]
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
# Session timeout. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
server.servlet.session.timeout= 
# Database schema initialization mode. [alwys | never | embedded]
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always 
# Path to the SQL file to use to initialize the database schema.(see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc)
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-@@platform@@.sql
# custom spring session table name (see : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1230) 
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
```

---

- In the jar/source ditribution, you'll find also "cleanup" (-drop) scripts
- and the currently provided platforms are:

  ```
  db2
  derby
  h2
  hsqldb
  mysql
  oracle
  postgresql
  sqlite
  sqlserver
  sybase
  ```

Comment: yeah I missed that part of `Initializer`. But it did not create the table SPRING_SESSION with my current config. How to execute the SQL provided by the spring session?

Comment: see edit (5. + 6.)! I think esp. important is 5. and (if you want the session schema initialized by spring boot): `spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always` and `spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-@@platform@@.sql` (where @@platform@@ refers to your database vendor/type).

Comment: point 5 and 6 are related to spring boot, so I am not using that config. So I run the script for creating the spring session tables with liquibase.

Comment: yea, this is an alternative, @MuhammadKholidB, you can find the sql files in the (spring-session) jar, respectively [at github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc)

Comment: ...but "5." might still be needed.... and set `initialize-schema=never` (for liquibase)

Comment: I don't think I need to add settings in my application.properties because it is not a spring boot project. Nothing will read that settings if I add it anyway.

Comment: Can you update your answer so I can mark it as accepted? It needs an update about how to create the tables needed by spring sessions which is my main question here.

Comment: avec plaisir! :)

Comment: This link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/samples/javaconfig/jdbc/ is dead. is there any other example snippet link available?

Comment: Hi, @Sulthan. This is the current link to the "spring-session-javaconfig-jdbc-sample": https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/spring-session-samples/spring-session-sample-javaconfig-jdbc ...i also updated in the post;)

Comment: Thanks @xerx593 . But the link is having the example with embedded (H2) database. Is there any example with MySQL or any other database?

Comment: The "only" (2-3) things, that you have to do, to switch this sample from h2 to mysql is: 1. change the h2 dependency to (appropriate) [mysql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) in `.gradle` file. 2. In `Config`class replace the `dataSource` definition with "the one you wish". 3. Delete `H2ConsoleInitializer` class. (please consider that this is a [tag:spring-session] specific sample (see sibling projects)). A mysql-specific spring-boot guide, can be found [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) , this can guide you with step 2.

Answer (score -1):

```java
@Autowired
    private Environment env;

@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager () {

        EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }


@Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory () {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.your.domain.project");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties()); // any addtional properties of your ORM
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        return factory.getObject();
    }


@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource () {

        final com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource comboDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        try {
            comboDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
            comboDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            comboDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
            comboDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.properties"));

        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return comboDataSource;
    }
```

This will definitely helps you.

Comment: Where do you use the spring session on that config?